# 2010 Designer Workflows Not Compiling in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

We have workflows built on the 2010 platform that are currently working in SharePoint Online.  If we save/republish them we now get the following error:
Workflow Error:  Errors were found when compiling the workflow.  The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.    Unexpected error on server associating the workflow.

If we check for errors none are found.  So far the only luck we've had is to delete the workflows and rebuild them using the 2013 platform.  This just started happening to multiple users 3 days ago. Examples of workflow changes include adding people to email distribution list or changing a hard coded link to one that uses workflowcontext.  I even tried compiling a workflow without making any changes and get the same error.

Can someone provide any suggestions of things we can try to resolve this?  Surely we shouldn't have to rebuild every workflow as changes are needed, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 3/7/2019, SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows stopped working on SharePoint Online sites, this issue is logged at Office 365 Admin Center > Health > Service Health > Advisories > SharePoint Online. Currently, it has not been fixed. If you meet this issue in your thread, you can suggest customers to check service health and wait for update.

After the above, you also should check the issue in Service health frequently, once this issue is fixed, please update it to your customers in your thread.

Comment: This issue has been fixed, please have a try again.